# Sphinx Search ranking by tags

Tags: php, mysql, search, sphinx, rank

I need to set the ranks order: by payed tags, after that by name etc.

For example: A client wants to buy the "car" tag. For the "car" search his profile should be first in the list.

Thanks

I have 2 tables:

1 - profiles : p_id, p_name, etc.

2 - tags : tag_id, profile_id, tag_name

And I want the keyword to match exactly the tag.

Comment: how do you store this data in db? show some schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use expression-based ranker and prioritize tags wight.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#weighting